# Grouping multiple user data with multiple timestamps

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (similar below) that I'm trying to deal with.

```
|   user  | weight | height | timestamp                       |
| ------  | -----  |------  |---------------------------------|      
| user 1  |   NA   |  180   | 2017-11-09 17:21:49.025259+00:00|
| user 1  |   90   |  NA    | 2017-11-09 17:21:49.025259+00:00|
| user 1  |   89   |  NA    | 2017-11-10 17:21:49.025259+00:00|
| user 1  |   88   |  NA    | 2017-11-11 17:21:49.025259+00:00|                             
| user 2  |   NA   |  175   | 2017-11-09 17:21:49.025259+00:00|   
| user 2  |   95   |  NA    | 2017-11-09 17:21:49.025259+00:00|
| user 3  |   NA   |  170   | 2017-12-09 17:21:49.025259+00:00|   
| user 4  |   70   |  NA    | 2017-08-09 17:21:49.025259+00:00|
```

My end goal is to calculate the BMI of each user, using the latest timestamp data of each weight and height. Some users only have one datum, many have more than one of weight, height, or both. Since the data are in kg and cm the BMI would be

BMI = (Weight in Kilograms  x 10,000)/((Height in centimeters)^2)

I am hoping to return something like the following. (a dictionary would be sufficient as well)

```
|   user  |         BMI       |
| ------  | ------------------|
| user 1  |   27.1604938272   |
| user 2  |   31.0204081633   |
| user 3  |        NA         |
| user 4  |        NA         |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert to datetimes
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
#sorting df by datetimes
df = df.sort_values('timestamp')
#for each group get last non NaN value
df1 = df.groupby('user').last()

#apply formula
BMI = (df1['weight'] * 10000 / (df1['height'])**2).reset_index(name='BMI')
print (BMI)
     user        BMI
0  user 1  27.160494
1  user 2  31.020408
2  user 3        NaN
3  user 4        NaN

#for dictionary
d = (df1['weight'] * 10000 / (df1['height'])**2).to_dict()
print (d)
{'user 1': 27.160493827160494, 
 'user 2': 31.020408163265305,
 'user 3': nan, 
 'user 4': nan}
```

Comment: Thank you! The .last() method is exactly what I needed.